# Windows 8.1 App Certification failing with no errors

Tags: windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

I am running the App Certification Kit 3.4 for my Windows store app before putting the package online. The app runs on my 64bit dev machine as well as my 32bit tablet.

I'm getting several AppCertKit errors:

**Package compliance test**
App manifest
Error Found: The app manifest test detected the following errors:
(Nothing is listed)

**App manifest resources test**
App resources validation
Error Found: The app resources validation test detected the following errors:
◦The test was blocked from execution. Please try re-running the validation. If the test execution remains blocked then please contact support.

Branding validation
•Error Found: The branding validation test encountered the following errors:
(Nothing is listed)

Several others, either Error found is empty or it says the Test was blocked.

Any suggestions for diagnosing this?